# Why do I get NullPointerException when use setCurrentText or setText for TextSwitcher?

Tags: android, listview, textview, nullpointerexception

`TextSwitcher` is part of `ListView` row (defined in xml). 
I define the text of TextSwitcher in the setViewValue:

```
switch(viewId) {
case R.id.tw_text:
    TextSwitcher twText = (TextSwitcher) view;
    twText.setCurrentText("test text");
    return true;
```

This code works perfectly if `twText` is `TextView`. But it returns NullPointerException with `TextSwitcher`:

```
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.TextSwitcher.setCurrentText(TextSwitcher.java:89)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at my.package.MainActivity$1.setViewValue(MainActivity.java:87)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:126)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:696)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-22 10:24:08.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3348):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update 1**: [looks like](http://android-argentina.blogspot.com/2010/11/android-tip-textswitcher-and.html) I need to add setFactory() to my code.
But if I do the following:

```
  TextSwitcher twText = (TextSwitcher) view;
  twText.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
      @Override
      public View makeView() {
      TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
      return t;
      }
      });
```

I am getting another error:

```
05-22 10:54:42.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3907): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't add more than 2 views to a ViewSwitcher
05-22 10:54:42.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.widget.ViewSwitcher.addView(ViewSwitcher.java:64)
05-22 10:54:42.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.widget.TextSwitcher.addView(TextSwitcher.java:67)
05-22 10:54:42.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1845)
```

**Update 2**: I've added `twText.removeAllViews()` before `twText.setFactory()`. It works, but looks like not the best way to delete and add Views again. How can I check if Views are already there?

Also, I would like to keep formatting/style of my TextSwitcher in the xml. Usage of setFactory doesn't allow me to do so. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like no views have been added to the text switcher at the point when `setCurrentText` is called. This method basically just gets current text view and sets the text for it, so if a `NullPointerException` appears, it may only happen due to the absence of the views in the text switcher.

Regarding the error with the factory: you have to be careful to either set a factory or to add two views yourself. You have either of these options:

- Call `setFactory` which will create two Views.
- Add two views manually by calling `addView`.

In both cases there can be only two views, no more no less. If you set a factory and some views have already been added, you will get an error. You can check if you need to set a factory by checking what `getChildCount()` method returns:

```
TextSwitcher switcher = (TextSwitcher) view;
if (switcher.getChildCount() != 2) {
    switcher.removeAllViews();
    switcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            return new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tested that both with `setCurrentText` and `setText` - the error is the same (so, I've just taken old code and new log ;). You are right that I haven't added any View there (strange, that it is not added by default). But how can I add it? Please see my updated question.

Comment: thanks for your help. I don't use `addView`. So, looks like `View`s are added automatically, since I use `TextSwitcher` in my xml. But somehow I can not use them. Or, this `setFactory` code is called several times (but my understanding was that each time it creates new Views there). I've updated the question again.

Comment: what should I do to force TextSwitcher views to use style (font size, color, position etc.) of TextSwitcher defined in xml?

Comment: When you apply a style to a `ViewGroup`, its children don't inherit its style anyway. Therefore, the best way to apply a specific style is to define your `TextView` in a separate XML file and inflate it in the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little too late on this but I found your question while I was searching for an answer to mine.  I was getting a similar error, can't add more than 2 views..., in an empty TextSwitcher when trying to call setFactory.  My issue was resolved when I changed my activity to extending Activity instead of ActionBarActivity.  Hopefully this will help some people in the future.

[TextSwitcher throwing "more than 2 views" error when setFactory() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176727/textswitcher-throwing-more-than-2-views-error-when-setfactory-is-called)